# JavaScript - setting multiple variables to object properties does not change underlying value

Tags: javascript

Recently, I have been working more with JavaScript and I cannot understand why the following happens.  Rather than providing hundreds of lines of code, I have created a scenario that recreates the problem.

**Issue:**

Setting multiple variables to an object's properties does not change the object's underlying value.

---

**Example:**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uy9v9/)

In the following example, I have created two classes:

```
//company
function Company(name, subsidiary) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.subsidiary = subsidiary;
};

//subsidiary
function Subsidiary(name, type) {
    var self = this;
    self.information = {
        name: name,
        type: type,
        type2: type
    };
}
```

Now, I do the following:

> - create a new company and add new subsidiary in the constructor:
> - define other variables related to the company/subsidiary properties

```
//new company
var company = new Company(
    'Company 1', [
        new Subsidiary('Subsidiary 1', 'small')
    ]),
    subsid = company.subsidiary[0], //get first subsidiary
    info = subsid.information, //get information
    type = info.type; //get type
```

The following code is where the problem lies:

When I try to change the variable *type*, the value within company does not change...

```
//does not work
type = 
    type === 'small' ?
    'large' :
    'small';
```

However, if I were to use *info* and reference the property *type* (`info.type`), the value changes...

```
//works
info.type2 =
    info.type2 === 'small' ?
    'large' : 
    'small';
```

I assumed since each variable derives from another, type would be equivalent to `company.subsidiary[0].information.type`, but that does not seem to be the case.

Am I missing something?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an object with a property called "type". You fetch the value of that property and put a **copy** of that value in a local variable called "type".  Subsequent changes to the local variable will not affect the object property value.

Your assumption:

> I assumed since each variable derives from another, type would be equivalent to company.subsidiary[0].information.type

is not correct. The JavaScript assignment operator represents a *value copy* operation. Thus,

```
var type = info.type;
```

means that the value of the object property should be copied as the value of the variable. Thereafter, there is absolutely no special relationship between the variable and the object property.

Then, here:

```
var info = subsid.information;
```

you're establishing a variable called "info" with a copy of the value of that "information" property. What is that value? It's a *reference* to an object. That's why a subsequent update actually changes the value of the real property in the original object.

There's no direct way to make a simple local variable be an alias for an object property in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I am still a little confused though. Wouldn't the variable `info` be a copy of `company.subsidiary[0].information`? Why would changing `info.type` change the value within company?

Comment: Because you're **explicitly** updating the value of the object property. I'll add a little bit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that! You did an amazing job at explaining what exactly is going on! Thanks again and I will accept your answer asap.

Comment: @Dom well JavaScript can be really confusing because it *looks* more like other languages than it actually is!